# Advanced NLG - robot journalist

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing

I want to produce a bot in Python that automatically generates short football summaries from Whoscored data. For my first stage I generate the articles with different sentence templates and lots of rules where the data is used.

Now I want to move to the next stage and start looking into NLP and more advanced NLG. I already scraped numerous articles to create a corpus. How should I move on and do next? Any advice would be much appreciated as I'm new in this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have summaries for a chunk of dataset? i.e. Is it a labelled dataset?